# program halts when compiling and reading data from file to array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, fstream

I wrote this program that calculates the total amount from file and store its to an array and stores twice the total in adjacent index. The program doesn't give any error when trying to compile but it doesn't display anything. I think my inner loop is wrong but not sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is whats on file

```
John Wilder: 33 44 45 80
Ron Carter: 27 14 55 23
John Wilder: 1 23 34 55
Ron Carter: 22 34 53 43
Test Line: 32 34 24 22
```

Here is the code that I wrote

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void storeArray(ifstream & file)
{
    int storeJohn[10] = {0};
    int storeRon[10] = {0};
    int totalNum = 0, eachNum = 0, counterJohn = 0, counterRon = 0;

    string firstLast; //store first name and last name
    //Logic
    while (!getline(file,firstLast,':').eof())      //Read the text from each line until it find ":"
    {
        if (firstLast == "John Wilder")
        {
            while (file >> eachNum)     //runs until end of line
            {
                totalNum += eachNum; //adds all the numbers
            }
            storeJohn[counterJohn] = totalNum;  //Store the total
            storeJohn[counterJohn + 1] = totalNum *2; //store twice the total

            totalNum = 0; //resetting for next line
            eachNum = 0; //resetting for next line
            ++counterJohn;

            if (counterJohn >=10)
            {
                continue; //Go to next line if the size is reached
            }

        }
        else if (firstLast == "Ron Carter")
        {
            while (file >> eachNum) //runs until end of line
            {
                totalNum += eachNum;
            }
            storeRon[counterRon] = totalNum;   //store the total
            storeRon[counterRon+ 1] = totalNum *2; //store twice the total

            totalNum = 0; //resetting for next line
            eachNum = 0; //resetting for next line
            ++counterRon; //After each loop counter goes up by one

            if (counterRon >= 10)
            {
                continue; //Go to next line if the size is reached
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout <<storeJohn[i] <<" "; //Displaying the array 
    }
    cout <<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
        cout <<storeRon[i] <<" "; //displaying the array
    }
    cout <<endl;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("records.txt");
    storeArray(file);
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend getting rid of the `.eof()` in ` while (!getline(file,firstLast,':').eof())` It can cause the program to miss a few possible failures, like the file not being open.

Comment: `storeJohn[counterJohn + 1] *= totalNum;` 0 times `totalNum` is...?

Comment: @user4581301 it should be *= 2. i will edit it

Comment: The problem is that your loop never passes the first line. Its always taking Jhon Wilder's line. You should read the complete line and split it later: split by colon (':') first, and split by space (' ') later to get all numbers independently.

Answer (score -1):

```
void storeArray(ifstream & file)
{
    int storeJohn[10] = {0};
    int storeRon[10] = {0};
    int totalNum = 0, eachNum = 0, counterJohn = 0, counterRon = 0;

    string firstLast; //store first name and last name
    //Logic
    while (!getline(file,firstLast).eof())      //Read the text from each line until it find ":"
    {
        istringstream buffer(firstLast);
        string name;

        getline(buffer,name,':');

        if (name == "John Wilder")
        {
            while (buffer >> eachNum)     //runs until end of line
            {
                totalNum += eachNum; //adds all the numbers
            }
            storeJohn[counterJohn] = totalNum;  //Store the total
            storeJohn[counterJohn + 1] *= totalNum; //store twice the total

            totalNum = 0; //resetting for next line
            eachNum = 0; //resetting for next line
            ++counterJohn;

        }
        else if (name == "Ron Carter")
        {
            while (buffer >> eachNum) //runs until end of line
            {
                totalNum += eachNum;
            }
            storeRon[counterRon] = totalNum;   //store the total
            storeRon[counterRon+ 1] *= totalNum; //store twice the total

            totalNum = 0; //resetting for next line
            eachNum = 0; //resetting for next line
            ++counterRon; //After each loop counter goes up by one

        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout <<storeJohn[i] <<" "; //Displaying the array 
    }
    cout <<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
        cout <<storeRon[i] <<" "; //displaying the array
    }
    cout <<endl;
}
```

Comment: when you use `while(file >> eachNum)`, you can read all the file.
So one idea is to make a buffer with each line, split it in ':'.

Comment: `while (!getline(file,firstLast).eof())` is bug-city.

Comment: you duplicate code, this is useless, non readable and a good way to have bug. do you will have 100 times the same code if 100 names have to be managed ? Wrong name detection, No protection against undefined behavior writing out of array etc ...